# How does non ECS parts work with ECS parts?

Tags: c++, architecture, entity-component-system

I incorporated ECS to my graphics engine and I have a problem with my `Renderer` needing the camera which is an entity and the process is a bit bizarre. Originally, I had a (and still do) `Scene` which had a reference to everything and the `Renderer` used that, but now with ECS the `Scene` no longer has game objects the `Renderer` needs to get that through the `EntityManager` so the `Renderer` now needs both these things.

My hack I guess was to have a reference of the camera in the `Scene` but the Renderer still needs to get it's components.

```
struct Scene {
    Entity camera;
    ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
};

Simulation::Simulation(Scene& scene, EntityManager& entityManager)
{
    // Loads scene
    Entity entity = entityManager.createEntity("Camera");
    entityManager.addComponent<CameraComponent>(entity, new CameraComponent());
    scene.camera = entity;
}

void Renderer::Draw(const Scene& scene, EntityManager& entityManager, const Resources& resources)
{
    Entity cameraEntity = scene.camera;
    CameraComponent& cameraComp = entityManager.getComponent<CameraComponent>(cameraEntity);
    TransformComponent& transformComp = entityManager.getComponent<TransformComponent>(cameraEntity);

    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(transformComp.translation, transformComp.translation + cameraComp.forward, cameraComp.up);
}
```

Perhaps the `Scene` could also keep the `EntityManager` so that they don't have to be passed separately and then use utility functions, but I'm not sure how I'd implement them.